# Explain overfitting / data leakage to a colleague

Tags: regression, logistic, experiment-design

I have a situation where we are calculating a customer life time value using some binary variables (ie have they purchased xyz widget?, etc.) and multiplying by a number that we believe approximates the value of these behaviors.

```
CLV = x1 * 500 + x2 * 300 + x3 * 100
```

The problem comes when a colleague wants to do a logistic regression to determine which customers will have CLV's above a certain threshold (ie `if CLV >= 1000, y = 1, else y = 0`)and use `x1`,`x2` and `x3` as variables.  I'm pretty certain this is a no-no as it's basically leaking info to the model but I'm having a hard time explaining this to my colleague.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before or know of a good source to explain this to someone who is math literate and intelligent but just doesn't have a ton of experience with modeling?

Comment: I don't see a problem here... You have a model and this logistic regression seems to be just a way of interpreting it, that's all. I guess I'm one of those guys who need that better explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key here is is OLS won't give you any new information. It might be significant, but it is circular reasoning. You created your weights based on some reason, and it gives you this CLV value. What might be interesting is to look at the unweighted relationship between x1, x2, and x3, and use that to predict someone is likely to pass your threshold.

So it isn't wrong... it's just a waste of time, I think.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm just waiting for Frank Harrell to tell you not to unnecessarily dichotomize)

Do you have any indication that the CPV should follow a logistic function of your $x$s?

Otherwise, I think what you are after is a [tolerance interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_interval) for the regression.
  I liked the explanations (in German) in [Nachweisvermögen von Analysenverfahren](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-28495-8/page/1). There's also a [paper in JSS](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v36/i05) which gives a general introduction before discussing how to calculate them.